# "which is to the best of our knowledge" vs "which to the best of our knowledge is"

Tags: word-order

I would like to know which one of the following is correct:

> 1. We ran the experiments on the XXX, which is to the best of our knowledge the largest publicly available sample of YYYs.
> 2. We ran the experiments on the XXX, which to the best of our knowledge is the largest publicly available sample of YYYs.

Comment: add a few commas and they are interchangeable

Comment: where should I add commas? @mplungjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both correct, but a little hard to read. You can use commas to parenthesize (or use parenthesis characters), thus:

> 1. ... on the XXX, which is, to the best of our knowledge, the largest ...
> 2. ... on the XXX, which, to the best of our knowledge, is the largest ...

In this case, I'd suggest the first is marginally preferable simply because it avoids having the "which" on its own, surrounded by commas. Even so, I'd actually suggest you split the sentence. Shorter sentences tend to be more readable.

> We ran the experiments on the XXX. To our knowledge, XXX is the largest publicly available sample of YYYs.